# Salesforce CLI Extension error: predicates_no_sfdx_project_found_text

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

In VSCode, I've installed 'Salesforce Extension pack'. As we know, it contains extenstion with name 'Salesforce CLI Integration'. This package is giving me below error :

```
 Missing Label!!! 
predicates_no_sfdx_project_found_text
```

In Notifications section(bottom right) in visual studio : it also shows this :

```
The extension 'Salesforce CLI Integration' took a very long time to complete its last operation and it has prevented other extensions from running.
```

Though all CLI commands etc are working but while coding, I've to type everything.

Comment: I'd suggest (1) uninstalling and reinstalling SFDX and the Extension Pack; (2) opening an Issue on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode).

Comment: thanks David!.. Just logged an issue in GitHub repo

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/3111

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too, choosing "Empty" while creating a new SFDX project.
Create a Standard project instead

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I change my project directory to a subfolder. I just opened the folder in correct folder and the error was gone. Might be just that directory changed for your project that might be the issue.